# Adding ffmpeg library to Python Kivy App and Buildozer for Android

Tags: python, android, ffmpeg, kivy, buildozer

I am working on a Python Kivy App, in which I have to manipulate audio files such as joining audio files or converting them into aac format. In order to achieve this I use the ffmpeg library. Everything works fine on my Linux machine, however, I couldn't make it run on the Android device. I build my apk/aab file by using Buildozer. I built a variety of cross-platform apps for Windows or Linux or for the web, but I am not really an experienced Android developer.

Can someone give me a high-level explanation or even a detailed description on how I can add this third party library to the apk/aab file and define it as environment variable using buildozer, so that other modules such as ffmpeg-python or pydub can find it? I am also open to alternatives if there are any.

I tried ffmpegkit, adding prebuilt libraries, defining the path to the converter in PyDub.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)